# Get data from android notification

Tags: android, notifications, data-retrieval

I am trying to extract some data from an android notification.
When I receive a mail, I can get the name of the sender from the title attribute and the rest of the notification is in the text attribute with the following code:

```
@Override
public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
    if (sbn.getPackageName().equals("com.google.android.gm") {
        String title = sbn.getNotification().extras.getString(Notification.EXTRA_TITLE);
        String text = "";
        text = sbn.getNotification().extras.getCharSequence(Notification.EXTRA_TEXT).toString();
        Log.i(TAG, "Title: " + title);
        Log.i(TAG, "Text: " + text);
}
```

Given now the following screenshot of a notification.
[Android mail notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVhxW.png)

The title is no longer the name of the sender (but 6 new messages) so I thought to take the text below and extract the name, but my code from above doesn't work because of an NullPointerException in line of text = sbn.getNotification()...

What am I missing or doing wrong? Does anyone know how to get the whole text or even a nice method to get the senders name?

Cheers